# Xcode6 Swift 動的なアイテムに対してのAutoLayout

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode6, storyboard, autolayout

Xcode6.4、言語:Swiftで開発を行っています。
Storyboardで縦のみスクロールのページを作っており、ScrollViewの上にUILabelやUIImageをのせています。
UILabelは複数あり、サーバーからAPI経由でLabelのテキストを動的に変更しています。
上から順にAutoLayoutの制約を決めているのですが、条件によって一部のUILabelを表示させたくない場合があり、それのAutoLayout設定がわかりません。

UIImageView　←　絶対に存在する

UILabel_1　←　絶対に存在する

UILabel_2　←　場合によって有無が変わる

UILabel_3　←　絶対に存在する

UIImageViewから下に5pxの位置にUILabel_1
UILabel_1から下に5pxの位置にUILabel_2
UILabel_2から下に5pxの位置にUILabel_3

仮にViewが上のようになっており、上から順にAutoLayout制約を設定している場合
UILabel_2がなかった場合レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。

UILabel_2のtextが空の場合はhidden=true、もしくはUILabel_2.text=""にすると、UILabel_2がある場所に余計な隙間ができてしまいます。

UILabel_2のtextが空の場合はUILabel_3の位置を
UILabel_1から下に5pxの位置にしたいです。（上につめるイメージ）

どのように実装したらよいのでしょうか。
ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 3):

ラベルとトップスペースの制約をアウトレット接続し、テキストの有無で`constant`の値を変更すればよい

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var topSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

... ... ...

// テキストをサーバーから受け取るなどした後

if (label.text!.isEmpty) {
  topSpaceConstraint.constant = 0
} else {
  topSpaceConstraint.constant = 5
}
```